# "Catch" unit testing framework - REQUIRE_THROWS_AS

Tags: c++, unit-testing, testing, catch-unit-test

I started to use "Catch" unit testing framework and so far it's really great. I have used VS built in unit testing framwork with great pain .

one thing I have noticed that the macro `REQUIRE_THROWS_AS` does not behave as one would expect

from the docs:

> ```
> REQUIRE_THROWS_AS( expression, exception type ) and
> CHECK_THROWS_AS( expression, exception type )
> ```
>
> Expects that an exception of the specified type is thrown during
>   evaluation of the expression.

when I try to write

```
TEST_CASE("some test") {
    SECTION("vector throws") {
        std::vector<int> vec;
        REQUIRE_THROWS_AS(vec.at(10), std::logic_error);
    }
}
```

I expect the test to fail and yet it says the test passed. is there a bug in the framework or I am wrong?

Comment: You call `vec.at(10)` -> it throws the exception `std::out_of_range` -> you say that you expect the exception `std::logic_error` to be thrown -> `std::out_of_range` *is* `std::logic_error` because it's a subtype of it -> everything's fine

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`std::out_of_range` (which is what `vector::at` should throw here) is derived from `std::logic_error`:

> No standard library components throw this exception directly, but the exception  types `std::invalid_argument`, `std::domain_error`, `std::length_error`, `std::out_of_range`, `std::future_error`, and `std::experimental::bad_optional_access` are derived from `std::logic_error`. -- [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/logic_error):

`REQUIRE_THROWS_AS` likely does something like:

```
try { expression; } 
catch (const exception_type&) { SUCCEED("yay"); return; }
catch (...) { FAIL("wrong exception type"); return; }
FAIL("no exception");
```

And due to the polymorphic nature of exceptions, the assertion passes.

Comment: I missed the part where `logic_error` is the base class of `out_of_range`. thanks